# remove log information from report and save report in desire location

Tags: robotframework

I am new to robot framework and wanted to see if i can get any simple code for custom report. I am also fine with answer to my problem. I went through all questions related to report but could not find any specific answer to my problem. currently my report contains log and wanted to see if i can remove log information from reports and save report in specific location. I just want to get PASS/FAIL information in my report. Can any one give me example how i can overcome this problem? I also need to know how i can save my report in different location. Any example would be helpful. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called Rebot which is part of Robot Framework.

By default, Robot Framework creates XML reports. The XML reports are automatically converted into HTML reports by Rebot.

You can set the location of the output files in the execution by specifying the parameter --outputdir (and thus set a different base directory for outputs).

From the documentaiton:

All output files can be set using an absolute path, in which case they are created to the specified place, but in other cases, the path is considered relative to the output directory. The default output directory is the directory where the execution is started from, but it can be altered with the --outputdir (-d) option. The path set with this option is, again, relative to the execution directory, but can naturally be given also as an absolute path. Regardless of how a path to an individual output file is obtained, its parent directory is created automatically, if it does not exist already. 
You can call Rebot yourself to control this conversion.

You can also run Rebot after the test was run in order to create new output on a different location.

See documentation in: 
http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#post-processing-outputs

The following example shows how to store the HTML reports in a different location and including only partial data:

```
rebot --include smoke --name Smoke_Tests c:\results\output.xml --outputdir c:\version1.0\reports
```

In the example above, we process the file c:\results\output.xml, create a new report called Smoke_Tests that includes only tests with the tag smoke and save it to the output folder c:\version1.0\reports

In addition you can also set the location of the log file (HTML) from the execution.

The command line option --log (-l) determines where log files are created.

The command line option --report (-r) determines where report files are created

Removing log lines can be done a bit differently. If you run rebot --help you'll get the following options:

```
 --removekeywords all|passed|for|wuks|name: *  Remove keyword data
                       from all generated outputs. Keywords containing
                       warnings are not removed except in `all` mode.
                       all:     remove data from all keywords
                       passed:  remove data only from keywords in passed
                                test cases and suites
                       for:     remove passed iterations from for loops
                       wuks:    remove all but the last failing keyword
                                inside `BuiltIn.Wait Until Keyword Succeeds`
                       name::  remove data from keywords that match
                                the given pattern. The pattern is matched
                                against the full name of the keyword (e.g.
                                'MyLib.Keyword', 'resource.Second Keyword'),
                                is case, space, and underscore insensitive,
                                and may contain `*` and `?` as wildcards.
                                Examples: --removekeywords name:Lib.HugeKw
                                          --removekeywords name:myresource.*
 --flattenkeywords for|foritem|name: *  Flattens matching keywords
                       in all generated outputs. Matching keywords get all
                       log messages from their child keywords and children
                       are discarded otherwise.
                       for:     flatten for loops fully
                       foritem: flatten individual for loop iterations
                       name::  flatten matched keywords using same
                                matching rules as with
                                `--removekeywords name:`
```

Comment: Thank You for response. I am using RIDE for my automation so wondering if i can set it in my scripts.

Comment: I tried with rebot --include smoke --name Smoke_Tests c:\results\output.xml but it still generate in default location. I tried with below example: rebot --include smoke --name Smoke_Tests c:\mylocation\reports\results\output.xml

Comment: I've edited the answer. Updated the example, and showed multiple ways of setting the location both from the execution and afterward.

Comment: Thank You. I tried with below code but it is not creating report in specific directory. rebot  c:\results\output.xml --outputdir c:\RunTestSuite\Reports

Comment: I tried with this rebot --name smoke_Tests C:\RunTestSuite\output.xml --outputdir C:\RunTestSuite\Reports but not working. It just created by default.